# Customize a delete selected confirmation page in the Django admin site

Tags: python, django

I need to show an additional alarm message in the delete selected confirmation page. The message should not appear always. It shoud appear depending on certain conditions.

I copied the `delete_selected_confirmation.html` template from the django/contrib/admin/templates/admin directory. I can now add an additional alarm message. But the message should appear depending on certain conditions.
Which function inside `class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)` should I use?

E.g., to set context for the `delete_confirmation.html` template I use `def render_delete_form(self, request, context)`.

Which function should I use for the `delete_selected_confirmation.html` template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to substitue the `delete_selected_confirmation.html` template, remove the `delete_selected` action, create your own action and use `django.contrib.admin.actions.delete_selected`. Here are a code scheme (`admin.py`):

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIRequest
from django.db.models import QuerySet

from .models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  
    actions = ["delete_selected_my_models"]

    def get_actions(self, request: WSGIRequest) -> dict:
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions
    
    def my_logic_comes_here(
        self,
        request: WSGIRequest,
        series: MyModel,
    ) -> bool:
        # ... My logic comes here
        return True

    @admin.action(description="Delete selected my models")
    def delete_selected_my_models(
        self,
        request: HttpRequest,
        queryset: QuerySet,
    ) -> TemplateResponse:
        template_response = delete_selected(self, request, queryset)
        if not request.POST.get("post"):
            show_alarm = False
            active_my_models = []
            for my_model in queryset:
                if self.my_logic_comes_here(request, my_model):
                    show_alarm = True
                    active_my_models.append(my_model)

            template_response.context_data["show_alarm"] = show_alarm
            template_response.context_data["active_my_models"] = active_my_models

        return template_response
```